# Magento 2 - Create a custom index.phtml before entering the site

Tags: magento2, php, customer, backend, forms

i would create a custom index.phtml for my site of magento before entering the site. In this index i would insert the form of registration of customers and after the registration the possibility to enter in the site.

My question is...it's possibile connect the form of registration in my index.phtml with the registration in backend of customers in Magento? If yes, how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a CMS page and in the layout section remove all unwanted blocks (ie: menu, footer, etc) then add *(to the CMS Page)* the registration blocks (see [that handle](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml))

[image]

**XML Update Detail:**

> Registration Form Part

```
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Probably you might want to remove some part ie: catalog menu:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Finally go to:

> Configuration > Web > Default Pages

and pick your CMS page in "CMS Home Page"

[image]